# PyCharm - cannot find Settings-Tools-Python Scientific

Tags: pycharm

I have seen posts that talk about this option for enabling plots:

> disable "show plots in tool window" from setting-->tools-->python
> scientific

I'm running `PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.6`
and I don't see any such option?  Has it been moved, or does it not exist in this edition?

Below is are my settings options:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That option group is available only in Professional edition. There you can see the full comparison https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

However, you can try it for free using EAP builds during the active EAP by the link https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/

More about EAP here https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2020/07/pycharm-eap-3-is-out/ https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2020/06/pycharm-2020-2-early-access-program-starts-now/

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out.  Does that mean that the Community Edition doesn't support displaying plots? My research showed that option was the secret to make the plots display.  I do see the Prof Edition is for scientific use - and maybe we are supposed to know that includes the plot capabilities?

Comment: You can see the full comparison here https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html. Scientific Tools is listed in the pro version, but missing in a community one

Comment: Also, you can always ask JetBrains itself on their issue tracker about the features, etc. Link is here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues . Or using `Help | Contact Support` in the IDE itself